# Microsoft DTV-DVD Video Decoder doesn't send samples

Tags: directshow

When I connect Microsoft DTV-DVD Video  decoder to my transform filter, it doesn't send media samples. It looks like it only sends samples when renderer is connected to it. Is there anything that my transform should satisfy in order to be connected to MS DTV-DVD video decoder (related to DXVA or something like that). **This happens only with some MOV files.** 
Here is connection between DTV-DVD and Renderer:

```
[Microsoft DTV-DVD Video Decoder]/(Video Output 1) -> [Video Renderer]/(VMR Input0)
      Major:   MEDIATYPE_Video
      Subtype: MEDIASUBTYPE_NV12
          bFixedSizeSamples:    TRUE
          bTemporalCompression: FALSE
          lSampleSize:          3342336
          cbFormat:             1152
      Format:  FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2
      VIDEOINFOHEADER2:
          rcSource:             (0,0,1920,1088)
          rcTarget:             (0,0,1920,1088)
          dwBitRate:            752026352
          dwBitErrorRate:       0
          AvgTimePerFrame:      333667
          dwInterlaceFlags:     129
          dwCopyProtectFlags:   1
          dwPictAspectRatioX:   1920
          dwPictAspectRatioY:   1088
          dwControlFlags:       679547009
      BITMAPINFOHEADER:
          biSize:               40
          biWidth:              2048
          biHeight:             -1088
          biPlanes:             1
          biBitCount:           12
          biCompression:        0x3231564E
          biSizeImage:          3342336
          biXPelsPerMeter:      0
          biYPelsPerMeter:      0
          biClrUsed:            0
          biClrImportant:       0
```

and here is the connection between DTV-DVD and my transform filter:

```
[Microsoft DTV-DVD Video Decoder]/(Video Output 1) -> [Video Transform]/(XForm In)
      Major:   MEDIATYPE_Video
      Subtype: {30323449-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}
          bFixedSizeSamples:    TRUE
          bTemporalCompression: FALSE
          lSampleSize:          3110400
          cbFormat:             1136
      Format:  FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2
      VIDEOINFOHEADER2:
          rcSource:             (0,0,1920,1080)
          rcTarget:             (0,0,1920,1080)
          dwBitRate:            746496746
          dwBitErrorRate:       0
          AvgTimePerFrame:      333333
          dwInterlaceFlags:     129
          dwCopyProtectFlags:   0
          dwPictAspectRatioX:   16
          dwPictAspectRatioY:   9
          dwControlFlags:       0
      BITMAPINFOHEADER:
          biSize:               40
          biWidth:              1920
          biHeight:             1080
          biPlanes:             1
          biBitCount:           12
          biCompression:        0x30323449
          biSizeImage:          3110400
          biXPelsPerMeter:      0
          biYPelsPerMeter:      0
          biClrUsed:            0
          biClrImportant:       0
```

Comment: maybe add some other intermediate filter or other?

Answer (score 1):

it has something to do with the dwCopyProtectFlags=1! I think the video is copy protected. I have the same problem, but didn't find an answer jet.
You can try it with an other decoder like ffdshow,