# DirectShow video stream ends immediately (m_pMediaSample is NULL)

Tags: c++, directshow, renderer

I have a [directshow](/questions/tagged/directshow) Video renderer redived from `CBaseVideoRenderer`. The renderer is used in a graph that receives data from a live source (BDA). It looks like the connections are established properly, but the video rendering immediately ends because there is no sample. However, audio Rendering works, ie I can hear the sound while `DoRenderSample` of my renderer is never called.

Stepping through the code in the debugger, I found out that in `CBaseRenderer::StartStreaming`, the stream ends immedately, because the member `m_pMediaSample` is `NULL`. If I replace my renderer with the EVR renderer, it shows frames, ie the stream is not ending before the first frame for the EVR renderer, but only for my renderer.

Why is that and how can I fix it? I implemented (following the sample from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152317/DirectShow-Filters-Development-Part-Video-Render) what I understand as the basic interface (`CheckMediaType`, `SetMediaType` and `DoRenderSample`), so I do not see any possibility to influence what is happening here...

**Edit:** This is the graph as seen from the ROT:
 [image: Running Object Table Entry]

What I basically try to do is capturing a DVB stream that uses `VIDEOINFOHEADER2`, which is not supported by the standard sample grabber. Although the channel is a public German TV channel without encryption, could it be that this is a DRM issue?

**Edit 2:** I have attached my renderer to another source (a Blackmagic Intensity Shuttle). It seams that the source causes the issue, because I get samples in the other graph.

**Edit 3:** Following Roman's Suggestion, I have created a transform filter. The graph looks like

[image: ROT of graph with grabber]

an has unfortunately the same problem, ie I do not get any sample (`Transform` is not called).

Comment: My best guess would be the problem in your filter: either you derived incorrectly or otherwise something went wrong but what you posted is hardly sufficient. Renderer is supposed to wait for samples, and from your description your renderer does the opposite and aborts.

Comment: I basically followed the sample from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152317/DirectShow-Filters-Development-Part-Video-Render, which only overwrites the very same methods. As I understand, the implementation of `CBaseVideoRenderer` should wait for the samples on behalf of me.

Comment: Custom video renderer does not look like adequate solution for missing `VIDEOINFOHEADER2` support in Sample Grabber.

Comment: Roman, what do you mean by that? As I understand, Microsoft's grabber cannot understand `VIDEOINFOHEADER2` and is also deprecated. Therefore, I see two options: either a custom renderer or a transform filter. As I understand, a transform filter is more complicated to write, so I tried the renderer (I am very new to DShow, so I might have got that wrong).

Comment: No, this is unrelated. Decoder might be able to connect to renderer using `VIH2`. Your change on renderer does not fix Sample Grabber's inability to support `VIH2`. Custom renderer is a VERY untypical task to do and transfor filter is easier to do. Then old SDK even have Sample Grabber like filter as a sample with full source, which you could pick as a base for your updates. All together, what you are doing does not look as an adequeate response to the problem mentioned.

Comment: OK, I understand what you mean: I do not want to "manipulate" the sample grabber via the renderer, but the idea was to use the renderer *instead* of the sample grabber (just grab the frames coming to `DoRenderSample`). I do not need the video being rendered at all, I want to send the frames over the network.

Comment: Could you give me a hint how old the SDK must be? I only went back to Windows 7 (which still has DShow stuff in contrast to Windows 8) and could not find it in the samples Directory.

Comment: The problem with standard renderers, even base classes supposed to reuse, that they have code to schedule samples, which you don't need in case you don't really present data (such as in case of network renderer, where you anyway are interested in certain buffering). So while eventually it would make sense to make it as renderer, the simplest well-reasoned solution is to use Sample Grabber + Null Renderer to get frame out out of the pipeline. That is, update on Sample Grabber - which is a very simple filter - is supposedly the easiest solution.

Comment: And please post and answer that I can give you some reputation if it works ;-)

Comment: `\DirectShow\Samples\C++\DirectShow\Filters\Grabber` here: "Microsoft® DirectX® 9.0 SDK Update (October 2004) Extras". You'll possibly have to chase for the download though. If my memory serves me right it was removed completely around Feb 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You supposedly chose wrong path of fetching video frames out of media pipeline. So you are implementing a "network renderer", something that terminates the pipeline to further send data to network.

A renderer which accepts the feed sounds appropriate. Implementing a custom renderer, however, is an untypical task and then there is not so much information around on this. Additionally, a fully featured renderer is typically equipped with sample scheduling part, which end of stream delivery - things relatively easy to break when you customize it through inheriting from base classes. That is, while the approach sounds good, you might want to compare it to another option you have, which is...

A combination of Sample Grabber + Null Renderer, two standard filters, which you can attach your callback to and get frames having the pipeline properly terminated. The problem here is that standard Sample Grabber does not support `VIDEOINFOHEADER2`. With another video decoder you could possibly have the feed decoded info `VIDEOINFOHEADER`, which is one option. And then improvement of Sample Grabber itself is another solution: [DirectX SDK Extras February 2005 (dxsdk_feb2005_extras.exe)](http://file.borlandforum.com/microsoft/DirectX9/dxsdk_feb2005_extras.exe) was the SDK which included a filter similar to standard Sample Grabber called Grabber `\DirectShow\Samples\C++\DirectShow\Filters\Grabber`. It is/was available in source code and provided with a good description text file. It is relatively easy to extend to allow it accept `VIDEOINFOHEADER2` and make payload data available to your application this way.

> The easiest way to get data out of a DirectShow graph, if youњre not going to use 
>   MultiMedia Streaming, is probably to write your own TransInPlace filter, a sub-variety 
>   of a Transform filter. Then connect this filter to the desired stream of data you wish to 
>   monitor, and then run, pause, seek, or otherwise control the graph. The data, as it passes 
>   through the transform filter, can be manipulated however you want. We call this kind of 
>   filter, a Њsample grabberћ.  Microsoft released a limited-functionality sample grabber 
>   with DX8.0. This filter is limited because it doesnњt deal with DV Data or mediatypes 
>   with a format of VideoInfo2. It doesnњt allow the user to receive prerolled samples. 
>   (Whatњs a preroll sample? See the DX8.1 docs) Its ЊOneShotћ mode also has some problems.

To add to this, the Grabber sample is pretty simple itself - perhaps 1000 lines of code all together, including comments.

Comment: Hmm. I have the transform filter, it is connected in the graph and the graph can run, but... `Transform` is never called. In other words, I have the same effect as before.

Comment: So you might be right it's about DRM, see [this Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372400/microsoft-dtv-dvd-video-decoder-doesnt-send-samples) and check media type on the video decoder output. Also you might at least try other decoders out to check whether they make it work.

Comment: `VIDEOINFOHEADER2::dwCopyProtectFlags` is 0 in my case - I wonder how that guy got this Information for the connection to the 3rd party renderer...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your decoder or splitter isn't demuxing the video frames. Look further up the chain to see what filters are supplying your renderer pin with data, chances are its only recognising audio.

Try dropping the file into Graphedit (there's a better one on the web BTW) and see what filters it creates.

Then look at the samples in the DirectShow SDK.

Comment: I have already checked the graph via the ROT. And as I said, if I add the EVR instead of my renderer, it shows the video. I would assume that the connection is OK if `OnStartStreaming` is called.